# What to do about programming questions

Tags: support, scope, migration

I think we have a consensus that programming questions are generally off-topic and belong on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). (I thought this was explicitly mentioned in the [FAQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) — is my memory failing or did it change?) [Borderline questions about the API are ok, but not questions about programming in C.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/unix-c-api-calls-ontopic)

So what do we do about [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11894/pci-device-driver-exporting-information-to-proc-file-system) which was migrated *from* Stack Overflow (by one Jeff Atwood)? I see a question about programming a Linux driver, firmly from the programmer's perspective, so I find it on-topic on Stack Overflow and off-topic on Unix Stack Exchange.

Jeff, could you explain this migration?

Comment: The trilogy FAQs have lines like "If your question would be of interest to... Professional and enthusiast programmers, ask on Stack Overflow."; I can't remember if SE2 sites ever did

Comment: @Michael: Has this ever been in the FAQ? (I thought I remembered it in the mod-editable part.)

Comment: [Doesn't look like it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/3258/revisions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree and think [that example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11894/pci-device-driver-exporting-information-to-proc-file-system) should be migrated back after a discussion on the MSO site so those guys understand why :)

Comment: We coordinate with the source site's mods when we reverse migrations, so that's not really a concern. I was going to leave it until Jeff commented, but I think I'm just going to do it now as long as the SO mods are fine with it. (**Edit**: it's back on SO now)