# What about questions accepting bash, python, C answers?

Tags: discussion

According to the fact hat C API questions are on-topic:

- [Unix C API calls ontopic?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/unix-c-api-calls-ontopic)

and this is not purely administrators site like https://serverfault.com/ ,

I'd like to ask questions accepting answers in:

- bash - it's obvious it's accepted here
- C - for similar reasons as : [Unix C API calls ontopic?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/unix-c-api-calls-ontopic)
- python - as more and more scripts are in python, and it provides interface to many C API syscalls, let's look stat as example : `os.stat(...)` and returns the same structure as original `stat` with `st_ino` etc.

Could you ensure me if I am right ?
If I miss something, please kindly let me know, or advice how to formulate question to reach my goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No and yes.

I can imagine bash-questions that are off-topic here (like: "How do I programm tic-tac-toe in bash").

The same will be true for C-questions that are not related to system-calls or system programming.

Python - again - if it belongs to system programming close to the operating-system level - yes.

Same will be true for `perl`, `awk`, `sed`, ... and all the other little helpers out there (which can be used for programs that are not os-related at all).