# An argument for the Unix-specific programming questions: site quality

Tags: discussion, scope

*If you think this suggestion would be against the newbies, then you maybe misunderstood. The goal of the suggestion is exactly the opposite: to attract more. Please read the details, it is important.*

---

First I would be glad to citate the [Area51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq):

*"The questions on your site say a lot about the community. To attract experts, you need a site where people are asking very interesting and challenging questions, not the basic questions found on every other Q&A site. Your goal is to make it clear that this is a professional site. "*

*"Remember, pro sites WILL attract the enthusiasts, but not the other way around!"*

Most of the questions request for help in some awk/sed/sh scripting or some similarly trivial task for a power user. Answering them is an easy way to collect reputation, but doesn't attract highly qualified visitors. For example, a developer of kernel drivers won't be here too long, because the topics which are interesting here for him, would be closed or migrated to the StackOverflow.

But the StackOverflow is a very broad mix of very different topics, asking highly specific things isn't really feasible there.

In my opinion, what should be allowed:

1. Programming questions about the standardized, unix-specific APIs. Especially about the posix standard.
2. Programming questions with deeply unix-specific object (especially kernel / libc hacking).
3. Programming questions about the internal workings of unix-specific software (some examples: kernels, apache module internals).

Of course it would result in some overlapping with the StackOVerflow. But I don't think that it would be harmful or problematic. The SO, being a very broad site, already has a lot of overlap with other SE sites (f.e. with Prog SE or Android).

The common (StackExchange-wide) consensus about the overlapping questions is that they remain, where they were opened (i.e. no migration, if it is ontopic on both sites).

In my opinion, if the Unix SE wants to attract the experts of an area, instead of being a help site where power users help not-so-power-users with configs and scripts, it should change to a behavior similar to the ProgSE - StackOverflow relation, and follow the more global, SE-wide consensus, instead of using a homebrewed, self-harming one.

---

*Extension: On the comments it seems to me as if you, dear reader, would think, I am argumenting against the enthusiast-level content. This is completely a misunderstanding, my argument is exactly the opposite: read my citation of the area51 faq. Having also high-level (i.e. programming) questions will attract **more** enthusiasts, and this is also a goal.*

Comment: Are you suggesting that configuring/administering a *nix system should be considered off topic?

Comment: @EricRenouf ??? I didn't write even any similar.

Comment: I was just wondering why you would list a set of programming things as what should be allowed, these then are just additional topics that you think right now would be migrated to SO instead of left here then?

Comment: @EricRenouf Yes, they are currently closed or migrated to SO, although the help center says libc / posix things are ontopic even if they are about programming. Related meta posts have mainly a negative consensus in this question, this is what I would like to change.

Comment: I agree with #3 -- that relates more to the internal design of Unix and Unix applications. But questions about how to write programs belong on SO, even if it's specific to Unix.

Comment: @Barmar Then you agree to lose the experts of the area. I am really wondering, for example, why should we send a kernel developer to the SO.

Comment: It's not a zero-sum game. Unix experts can participate on both forums: SO for programming questions, UL for design and usage questions.

Comment: @Barmar No. Trivial scripting and tool/daemon configuration won't attract them. Maybe you should read that Area51 FAQ I've linked.

Comment: I think that FAQ betrays an idealistic attitude about StackExchange sites that hasn't been achieved in general. When I first joined SO, I thought it was going to be expert (or at least experienced) programmers helping each other with challenging problems. I've since learned that at least 90% of the questions come from newbies needing everything spoon-fed to them. Yet the site hasn't failed due to lack of experts.

Comment: @Barmar 1) SO is far over the critical mass needed for the long-term survival, unix SE isn't 2) There are a lot of high-level expert questions there as well, here it is forbidden 3) I think you didn't read the Area51 FAQ I've linked, maybe you should. 4) My argument is about the quality of the site, and not about its survival.

Comment: @peterh no, Barmar is right in that FAQ is a bit idealistic. For example, another site which had a debate about "expert"ness is [english.se]: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/this-is-not-a-site-for-serious-english-language-enthusiasts-and-it-never-will

Comment: Also related: programming Ubuntu apps is on-topic on Ask Ubuntu (you'll see quite a few QML questions there). The on-topic section has the overly broad "Development on Ubuntu" line, but in practice, it usually comes out to allowing questions on Ubuntu-specific APIs.

Comment: @muru Your [comment](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/an-argument-for-the-unix-specific-programming-questions-site-quality?noredirect=1#comment5670_3657) is completely unrelated to the subject, I would suggest to read the original post again. This post is not about the "askubuntu" site, this post is about that we shouldn't expel the experts to the SO.

Comment: @muru (Reacting [this](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/an-argument-for-the-unix-specific-programming-questions-site-quality?noredirect=1#comment5669_3657)) It is not about elitism, it is only about to not expelling the experts.

Comment: @muru No. :-) Unfortunately, it is simply not clear to me, what is your stance about the expelling of the unix programmers from the Unix SE. You didn't make it clear in your 5 comments. Honestly, I really won't debate about askubuntu and other sites. I want to debate about the expelling of the programmers from the Unix SE.

Comment: @peterh my stance is expressed by the upvote I made. The comments are pointers to how other Stack Exchange sites deal with this, so that we can learn from it, nothing more.

Comment: @muru Well, it seems I completely misunderstood you.I am sorry.

Comment: @muru My answer after reading your referenced topic: no, it is _not_ about any type of "supression" or scripting, shell programming, etc. My argument is to _extend_ the site, with high-level content - partially with the goal to attract _more_ enthusiast-level scripting/config questions, too. This is what the area51 faq also says: expert content _attracts_ enhusiasts, but enthusisast content doesn't attract experts. There is no such thing as "low end OR elitist" site, this is not mathoverflow. There is a BIG site, all about *x, with many questions, this what I want.

Comment: @slm Thank you :-)

Comment: newbies asking *good* but trivial questions is an opportunity to pass on the 'lore' to the next generation, not just to the asker but to anyone else who reads it.   Some newbies and some readers will become the next generation of experts.

Comment: @cas I already said twice, that my suggestion is exactly the same: because expert content attracts also enthusiast questions (but not the other way around). The current site policy expels a large part of the expert questions saying that "programming questions are belonging to the SO", although these could attract more questions on _every_ skill level. The goal is to attract more new users (on every skill level!), which happens more effectively if there is also programming content here.

Comment: It sounds like you are, or should be, arguing for a Unix & Linux Programming SE.   No matter how unix programming and API questions are treated here, they'll be swamped by all the other questions, defeating your goal of attracting highly-qualified experts in *nix programming.

Comment: @cas Why? Unix-unix. I would find any topic about Unix very interesting. Forbidding Unix programming on a Unix site, this is what I find disattractive.

Comment: Actually, the Unix API [_is_ on topic](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/2875/22222). What's not on topic is asking about the details of implementing something in C. Asking about which library/system call to use is fine, asking about how exactly you can use it in your program is not. This site's scope is more about system administration and configuration than about hard core programming.

Comment: @terdon _"Asking about which library/system call to use is fine, asking about how exactly you can use it in your program is not."_ The second part is actually a rubber paragraph, a trap: it filters out the clearly formulated questions, while allows the unclear ones (which could be still closed as unclear). Does an intra-mod agreement, or a said or unsaid rule from the CMs exist which tries to minimize the programming content out of the SO?

Comment: @peterh not as far as I know, no. In any case, that wouldn't even be possible. A site's scope is defined by the site's community, not SE and not the mods. I'm just pointing out that part of what you seem to be asking for is already here. Then, as a regular user, I personally don't want C programming to be on topic here but that's just my own opinion.

Comment: @terdonAs you can see on the meta, the community isn't engaged to modify the rule on the spot, many of them don't even understand it correctly. It is highly unfortunate, and it seems unsolvable. I would leave this suggestion as a signpost for the googlers of the future, maybe sometimes we will have enough support to change this harmful directive.

Comment: Thanks for asking for including Unix/Linux programming questions. It is a request by more than just you. Please keep up the push, and give some support here https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5697/lets-return-to-the-full-meaning-of-unix-linux, so that it can become visible

Answer (score 4):

I generally agree with the following statement in the question.

> 1. Programming questions about the standardized, unix-specific APIs.
>    Especially about the POSIX standard.
> 2. Programming questions with deeply unix-specific object (especially
>    kernel / libc hacking).
> 3. Programming questions about the internal workings of unix-specific
>    software (some examples: kernels, apache module internals).

There is actually no clear concensus on this issue, as you can see from the question [Is the Unix C API still on-topic?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2875/4671), where derobert and myself spoke for (roughly speaking), and Gilles spoke against. And there does not appear to be a clear mechanism within Stack Exchange for clarifying scope. Such decisions would presumably be needed to be made by some kind of voting mechanism or by some hypothetical higher authority, and no such procedure exists.

There also seems to be a lot of hairsplitting/debate over whether a C question (for example) about the C API is really a question about C the programming language or really about the Unix C API. As you can see, I favor not worrying about this that much, and allowing questions which involve asking about the C API as long as the C API is an significant part of the question. I.e. the C API could not easily be substituted by something else in the question. A question which is really a C programming question, say where the question is how to include headers in a C file, and which involves Unix content only incidentally should be moved to Stack Overflow, I agree.

It is also true that there is a gray area here, but in case of doubt, I favor coming down more strongly on the side of inclusion vs the side of exclusion.

In practice it seems that such questions end up getting closed, but this is more a reflection of the fact that the people who don't like such questions close or migrate  them, and the people who are fine with them don't vote to reopen. I'm not sure why this is. Perhaps they don't want to have more arguments.

[Please explain “kobject”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/261525/4671) is a recent question, for example, that I consider to be on-topic here. However, others apparently disagree. This is, in your words, a "deeply Unix-specific" question. It's not a good question, but that's a separate issue.

I also agree with your view that Unix system stuff should be an important part of a Unix site like this one. Specifically, when you write

> Most of the questions request for help in some awk/sed/sh scripting or
> some similarly trivial task for a power user. Answering them is an
> easy way to collect reputation, but doesn't attract highly qualified
> visitors. For example, a developer of kernel drivers won't be here too
> long, because the topics which are interesting here for him, would be
> closed or migrated to the StackOverflow.

To some extent I think this also reflects the fact that the current membership is interested in things like shell programming, which is considered to be more of general interest, while Unix programming type stuff is considered to be of marginal/minority interest. It's true that we (probably) would not want to be overrun by the Linux Kernel mailing list, but I doubt that is an issue,any more than being overrun by Debian development mailing lists.

(Answering late, because I just saw this question - nobody pointed me to it.)

Comment: Well.. the problem is very clear: higher level questions are theoretically allowed, but practically we have the 5 3k+ assholes which is enough to ruin a SE site. Polite communication won't work with them. Rude communication also won't work. The site is dead.

Comment: Yes, they will stop any communication which is over their skills. Yes, they close any programming questions because they are stupid for that. Yes, they won't ever admit it. Yes, they only want some like of false sense of power here and not a high level communication channel. Gilles is an exception, he is not idiot, but it seems he will follow what the idiots want. Yes, they are stronger as we. I don't know what to do, I don't contribute to this site since this is clear to me. And this is clear to me since I posted this meta question. This site is dead for me.

Comment: Hehe, the joke of the day: yesterday afternoon I've got a serial downvote. It seems I have an anti-programming fan.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica This site does little about the attacks. Changes always happen from the bottom up.

Comment: Thanks for support of including Unix/Linux programming questions. It is a request by more than just you. Please keep up the push, and give some upvote here https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5697/lets-return-to-the-full-meaning-of-unix-linux, so that it can become visible again or avoid becoming invisible again.