# Is a question regarding wpa_supplicant modifications for a research project on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

(Here != Meta-Unix&Linux)

I have a question related to a research project I am undertaking that involves knowing **which files related to `wpa_supplicant` need to be modified** to accomplish my goal of emulating/simulating certain wireless channel characteristics. While this will be a programming heavy task, the necessary answer will require extensive knowledge of how Linux WiFi drivers interact with this Linux module and perhaps how the configuration files will need to be set up.

Do you think this question would be best served on the Unix & Linux StackExchange site?

(Edit: Here is the question being referenced [Simulating Signal Strength Changes to wpa_supplicant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193871/108864))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. As long as you're not asking about how to implement whatever it is you're doing in programming language X but instead are asking about the internals of how `wpa_supplicant` works, then yes, it should be perfectly on topic here.

In fact, even questions about interacting with the UNIX API are [on topic within reason](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/314/22222). In other words, if you know your C but have questions about how to interact with a *nix system, they will be welcome here. If your question is not so much about the API but about how to implement something in C, then it should go to SO.

Comment: Good to know. I am not asking about the *how*, but rather the *where*. Thanks for your response; I will post this on the main site.