# Flood of off-topic flags, is this the norm here?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, flagging

I just reached the rep to get into the close votes review queue.  What I see there are a lot of off-topic flags with which I often do not agree.  That's sketchy so I'll add two examples:

- [Midnight Commander opens file wrong](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245260/midnight-commander-opens-file-wrong).  Midnight commander is often regarded a an MS windows application but there is a GNU mc for Linux.  And GNU mc is certainly on topic.
- [Find CPU times and system times of process in linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316132/find-cpu-times-and-system-times-of-process-in-linux).  Well yeah, that's C code, but the question appears to be about the `execlv` syscall, and [C syscalls are on topic](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/unix-c-api-calls-ontopic).  The question is not well written though, and I'd argue that it falls under the "unsure what you are asking" flag, but not under the off-topic flag.

I'm asking because I'm not sure whether it is community consensus to flag these questions as off-topic (and therefore I'm doing the opposite work by rejecting the flags and I should stop).  Or it is just a lack of attention of some users that may be flagging questions at 4AM.

So yeah, are these questions really off-topic?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, congratulations and welcome to the janitorial staff! Now, finding things you don't agree with in the review queues is quite normal. That's why they're reviewed, after all. If you don't agree that a question should be closed (by the way, those are close votes, not flags), then vote to leave it open and move on. That's how it works.

As for your specific examples, personally, I consider them both off topic:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245260/midnight-commander-opens-file-wrong is not being closed as off topic because anyone thought it was a Windows program (hell, I didn't even know there was a Windows `mc`, it's always been a *nix thing for me), it's being closed as "Off Topic -> Non reproducible" which is something else again. That's because the OP stated that they found a solution in the settings, but didn't post an answer. Since this is such a very minor issue which seems to be solvable anyway and it is an old question, closing it as non-reproducible makes sense.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316132/find-cpu-times-and-system-times-of-process-in-linux is a C question pure and simple. Yes, it happens to use a Unix-C API call, but the question itself is not about the API or how to use it, so it isn't on topic here.

Comment: Oh, I get it now.  Notably the 2nd part about the subtle difference in *"how to use the C API"* and *"how do i use C to perform A whilst using the Linux API"*.

Comment: I am in a similar situation as @grochmal, I simply lack some routine. I find the label "Off-topic" for trival questions a bit misleading. I think I need to get used to it.

Comment: @countermode what do you mean? Whether a question is on topic or not has nothing to do with whether it is trivial. "How can I set a variable to an integer in C" is trivial but also completely off topic.

Comment: This was not related to this specific case. It was related to "Off Topic -> Not Reproducible" which includes trivial stuff like mis-spelling commands and the like.

Comment: @countermode well, the rationale there is that if I ask "why does `echoo foo` fail?", that is very unlikely to ever help anyone else since the issue is so obviously a typo, so closing such questions is better for the site. Keeping questions that aren't likely to help future visitors just clutters up the site with noise while not providing anything useful. Hence, off topic.

Comment: As I said, I need more routine end experience, although I get along pretty well already.

Comment: I disagree with your argument on the ‘CPU times’ question.  It is not asking “How do I add numbers in C?”; it is “How do I get this system information from the Unix/Linux kernel (using the C API)?” It’s not about the programming language; it’s about the OS. A [SO] user could be an expert on C programming and have no idea how to answer this question. We always talk about how many of the sites overlap: AU and U&L; U&L and SU; and scripts can go lots of places. Questions about the Unix-C API should be in the overlap between U&L and SO, and should stay in the community where they were asked.

Comment: I expected that you would refer me to the U&L on-topic guidelines, and I was prepared to argue that they should be changed. Taking questions about process properties and shoving them over to SO is overzealous compartmentalization — if `/proc`, `strace`, and scripts are on-topic, then the mere mention of C should not push a question over the edge. But then I saw something I had forgotten — the [Help Center](/help/on-topic) explicitly says that “UNIX C API and System Interfaces (within reason)” are on-topic. So I don’t understand how you can say that the ‘CPU times’ question is off-topic at U&L.